# After clicking a link, URL changes but navigation is not commenced

Tags: angular, router, ngrx

I've just recently moved to ngrx's router from angular2's router.
Also, I am using angular 2 rc4.

my routes look like this:

```ts
export const: Routes = [
    {path: "appRoute1", component: "appComponent1", guards: [HashGuard, hasSelectedGuard]},
    {path: "appRoute2", component: "appComponent2", guards: [HashGuard, hasSelectedGuard]},
]
```

HashGuard only has one function (and a constructor):

```ts
protectRoute(candidate : TravesalCandidate){
    if (!window.location.hash){
        this.router.go(HOME_ADDRESS);
    }
    return Observable.of(true);
}
```

similarly, HasSelectedGuard has only one function:

```ts
protectRoute(candidate : TravesalCandidate){
   if (!this.currentSelectionService.hasSelectedPerson()){
       this.router.go(HOME_ADDRESS);
       return Observable.of(false);
   }
   return Observable.of(true)
}
```

I am bootstrapping whatever's needed, as I should have:

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    provideRouter(routes, HashLocationStrategy), 
    Router, 
    HashGuard, 
    CurrentSelectionService
]
```

I have a sidemenu component with multiple links, along others I have appRoute1 and appRoute2:

```html
<a [linkTo]="'/appRoute1'"> ... </a>
<a [linkTo]="'/appRoute2'"> ... </a>
```

When I click one of the links the URL changes as supposed to, but the page itself does not load (no requests are sent after the click and the component's constructor is not

Help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: sorry, I was confused, we're using ngrx's router.

Comment: Sorry for the confustion, I checked for the `ngrx` tag and still didn't see it :D

Comment: Edited to better reflect my setup, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reverting to Angular's component and using `router.navigate([URL])`.

At the time of writing, NgRX's router was still incompetant.